# How to pact test an SSE endpoint (GET, "Content-Type": "text/event-stream")

Tags: server-sent-events, pact

My current application includes an SSE endpoint to allow streaming access to events occurring internally.  That all works well, but we're like to do contract testing using pack for all endpoint and I can't find a way to define a pact for the stream event data, which looks like this:

```
data: {"foo": "bar"}

data: {"bar": "foo"}

...
```

in curl results.

Can anyone point me to an example of a pact for SSE contract validation?

Answer (score 1):

Pact has a concept referred to as Message Pact. Message pact support asynchronous calls, and abstracts away the specific protocol.

Which language do you need?

For example, here is the docs for Pact JS: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/#asynchronous-api-testing

An example consumer test for a product event would look as follows:

```js
describe("receive product event", () => {
  it("accepts a product", () => {
    return (
      messagePact
        .given("product created")
        .expectsToReceive("a product created event")
        .withContent({
          id: like(1),
          name: like("pizza"),
        })
        .withMetadata({
          "content-type": "application/json",
        })
        .verify(synchronousBodyHandler(productApiHandler))
    )
  })
})
```